# what's the use of transformer_weights in scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

It's just a little question of scikit-learn's pipeline.

In the class `sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion` , there is a `transformer_weights` option .

> transformer_weights: dict, optional
>   :    Multiplicative weights for features per transformer. Keys are transformer names, values the weights.

I saw the use in an example that give different weight to different feature.

```
    transformer_weights={
        'subject': 0.8,
        'body_bow': 0.5,
        'body_stats': 1.0,
    },
```

It's nonsense to me, because the classifier will learn the weighting for you later. Why bother using it at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a linear classifier with penalty, this will change the amount of penalty applied to each block of features.
Scaling features up will mean they will be less penalized relative to the other features.

Comment: Is there a way to test different weights, similar to other parameters in a grid search?

Comment: You can search them using grid-search if you like.

Comment: How do I access them, since they're not assigned a label like the transformers it classifiers?

Comment: You need to use the master branch as that was recently fixed btw.

Comment: if you do ``make_pipeline(make_union(Tranformer1(), Transformer2()), Classifier())`` then ``param_grid={'featureunion__transformer_weights' : [[1, 1], [.1, .9], [10, 1000]]}`` should work.

Comment: I know this was answered quite a while ago, but I just wanted to add that I tried this solution and ran into a problem. You are able to pass in a list of lists and it will run, however it won't work as expected, you need to pass in a dictionary with the keys being the names of the segments of the feature union e.g. `make_pipeline(make_union(Tranformer1(), Transformer2()), Classifier()) then param_grid={'featureunion__transformer_weights' : [dict(subject=1, body_bow=2), dict(subject=.1, body_bow=.9) ]} `